# How to add a specific point to a ggroc() curve?

Tags: r

I'm trying to add a specific point to my ROC curve using:

```py
g <- ggroc(c.roc, size = 0.8) + 
  labs(x="specificities", y = "sensitivities")

g  + ggplot(tibble(sensitivities=3.9558923, specificities=0.8552395), aes(x=sensitivities, y=specificities)) +
  geom_point(colour="blue")
```

but doesn't work:

> Error: Don't know how to add ggplot(tibble(sensitivities = 3.9558923,
>   specificities = 0.8552395),     aes(x = sensitivities, y =
>   specificities)) to a plot

Comment: Why do you have #c in your title? Also, please specify the data and packages you've used. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is `ggroc() + ggplot() + geom_point()`, which is essentially `ggplot() + ggplot() + geom_point()`. Much like `ggplot`, `ggroc` expects a geom layer, and not another data layer. To add new data you can pass it into your geom. This should work:

```r
g <- ggroc(c.roc, size = 0.8) +
    labs(x="specificities", y = "sensitivities")

# You don't need ggplot. Just pass data into your geom.
g + geom_point(data = tibble(sensitivities=0.9558923, # Should be less than one.
                             specificities=0.8552395
                             ),
               mapping = aes(x=sensitivities, y=specificities),
               colour = "blue")
```

Just make sure `colour` is outside of `aes`. Also note that ROC x and y scales are 0 to 1, which means a `sensitivities = 3.9558923` will put the point outside of the plotting area. I've changed it to 0.9558923 above.

Comment: I have tryed and the point doesn't appear and R return: Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

Comment: @LaiaEC ROC plots use x and y scales between 0 and 1, which means `sensitivities=3.9558923` will put the point outside of plotting area.